# How to create formula based upon text on page

Tags: microsoft-excel, worksheet-function

I have table which looks like

```
Mar2019      Feb2019
  3             5
  4             6
```

The numeric values are brought in from another worksheet. As such, the first value under Mar2019 (which is the value 3), has the following formula

```
=('Mar2019'!$B2)
```

As you can see from the formula above, the formula references the worksheet 'Mar2019', which is also the column name in the table.

I was hoping to update the formula to

```
=A1!$B2
```

(where A1 is the column title 'Mar2019') but this doesn't work.

I even tried hacking it with

```
=CONCAT(A1)!$B2
```

Is what I want to do possible

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to use [`INDIRECT`](https://support.office.com/en-us/article/indirect-function-474b3a3a-8a26-4f44-b491-92b6306fa261) function:

`=INDIRECT(A1&"!$B2")`

Comment: Perfect, thank you. Will this though prevent me dragging the formula down over multiple rows? I know I can update to use `row`, such as `$A$1&"!$B"&ROW()` but was curious

Comment: exactly, using `$A$1&"!$B"&ROW()` as in your comment will let you to fill down the formula.